# How to implement the animation of changing the span count in the RecyclerView by gesture, like Google Photos app?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, gallery, photo

I want implement the animation effect of changing the number of columns in the RecyclerView using a two-finger gesture, similar to the Google Photos app or ios photos. But i have no idea to make it.

sorry i have no ideas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.